# How to compile deskew plugin for Gimp?

Tags: compiling, gimp

I'm interesting in using this Deskew plugin which appears somewhat old, with broken links in the [gimp registry](http://registry.gimp.org/node/2958).

https://github.com/prokoudine/gimp-deskew-plugin

How do I go about installing it on Ubuntu 64-bit 12.10 running Gimp 2.8? I can't figure what I have to "configure" or "make" to compile the plugin. I understand the end result should be placed

Noob-level: I know how to get around in a terminal, but that's about it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how to compile the [deskew plugin](https://github.com/prokoudine/gimp-deskew-plugin) for `Gimp`. It is largely trouble free, but I will note certain important things as I go along. This should work across all `Gimp` 2.x versions; it has been tested successfully on `Gimp` versions 2.6 and 2.8.

Firstly, you need the Gimp development files, and the most important one is `libgimp2.0-dev` as it contains the header files necessary for compiling plugins for `gimp`.

```
sudo apt-get install libgimp2.0-dev
```

I already had the other gimp development files installed, as I had run `sudo apt-get build-dep gimp`, but you shouldn't need them for this one plugin.

Now pull the code from git with:

```
git clone git://github.com/prokoudine/gimp-deskew-plugin.git
```

Then cd to the `gimp-deskew-plugin` folder and run

```
./autogen.sh
```

I would normally specify `--prefix=/usr` here, as we don't want the plugin installed in `/usr/local`, however it doesn't install correctly in the `/usr` hierarchy, but I will explain how to overcome that later.

Now, run `make` and the plugin executable is compiled in a few seconds.

As running `sudo make install` doesn't quite get it to where we want it (even with specifying a prefix earlier), it is necessary in this case to manually copy the one executable to the `Gimp` plugins folder:

Cd to `~/gimp-deskew-plugin/src` and run

```
sudo cp deskew /usr/lib/gimp/2.0/plugins
```

The plugin is now accessible from Gimp > Layer > Transform > Deskew.

[image]

Comment: On Debian I had to copy into sudo cp deskew /usr/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins note the "-" between plug and ins Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just a heads up. I fixed this in the Git repo and moved the repo over here:

https://github.com/gimp-plugins-justice/gimp-deskew-plugin