# how to install webp plugin for gimp?

Tags: compiling, plugins, gimp, webp

how to install [gimp webp plugin](http://registry.gimp.org/node/25874)? I found out that we can do it using with gimp-plugin-registry, but donno how. I have install gimp-plugin-registry extension for gimp from ubuntu software center, now what should i do?

I also found out that we can put plugins in `/usr/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/`, so i tried to compile the [gimp webp plugin src](http://registry.gimp.org/files/gimp-webp_0.1.1.tar.gz). I installed `libwebp-dev` and ran `make` in plugin source folder. It says

```
Package gtk+-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
```

so i decided to install `libgtk` package but i found both `libgtk2.0-dev` and `libgtk-3-dev`. Is libgtk-3-dev is latest release of the libgtk2.0-dev? If so is it ok if I installed the later one?

I want to know at least how to install the plugin with gimp-plugin-registry and i will be more happy if i can do it by compiling src.

----------EDIT----------

I've installed libgtk-3-dev and ran `make` and it threw same error, I carried on with libgtk2.0-dev, Now it throws `Package gimp-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path`. There is no gimp-dev in repositories! I got stuck!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to view WebP images in nautilus / photo program?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/61443/is-it-possible-to-view-webp-images-in-nautilus-photo-program)

Comment: You need to run `sudo apt-get install libgimp2.0-dev`; that should make compilation possible. My [answer for this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/220771/how-to-compile-deskew-plugin-for-gimp) might be helpful.

Comment: The latest version of the source is available here: http://registry.gimp.org/node/25874 I believe gimp 2.6 may be required

Answer (score 9):

> **Note:** the WebP plugin is going to be included in the next version of the Gimp (version 2.8+) as a built-in plugin (later, this plugin [was shipped in GIMP 2.9 branch](https://www.gimp.org/news/2017/08/24/gimp-2-9-6-released/#webp-support), and received multiple improvements). The PPA can still be used to enable WebP support in the meantime.

I have updated the packages available in [the WebP PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Egeorge-edison55/+archive/ubuntu/webp/) to the latest Ubuntu releases. After adding the PPA, you can use the plugin simply by installing the `gimp-webp` package.

I also migrated the plugin over to CMake, so building the plugin is a lot easier now:

1. Install the following packages:

   ```
    sudo apt-get install build-essential git cmake libgimp2.0-dev libwebp-dev
   ```
2. Checkout the source code:

   ```
    git clone https://github.com/nathan-osman/gimp-webp
   ```
3. `cd` to the new directory and create a `build/` directory:

   ```
    cd gimp-webp
    mkdir build
    cd build
   ```
4. Build the plugin:

   ```
    cmake ..
    make
   ```
5. Install the plugin:

   ```
    sudo make install
   ```

That's it!

Comment: The indicated PPA doesn't work for Xenial 16.04. Error message: `E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/george-edison55/webp/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file. N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.`

Comment: @PaddyLandau I'll issue a build for Xenial.

Comment: The Xenial build works. Thank you for being so quick!

Comment: Hi @NathanOsman I couldn't find the bionic release on the repository, it's dismissed?